# ACTION_DOWN but pointers are already down. Probably missing ACTION_UP from previous gesture

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-tabactivity

I have a list view inside a tab which is inside another tab for the first time it showing when I am clicking a list this alert is showing properly.But when I am clicking another list without changing tab it showing this error

```
TouchEvent: ACTION_DOWN but pointers are already down.  Probably missing ACTION_UP from previous gesture.
```

**My alert looking like this**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //inflater.inflate(R.menu.downloadmennu, menu);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Question_Download.this.getParent().getParent());

    alertDialog.setTitle("Make your choice...");
    alertDialog.setMessage("What do you want to download?");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.save_file_floppy);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Mock Exam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            downloadOptionSelected = DownloadOptions.MockExam;
            isMock = true;
            AppPreferenceStatus.setStudyDownload(CurContext,CourseMatIntent.MockExam);
            MockExamActivity(chapterPosition);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Study Mats.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            downloadOptionSelected = DownloadOptions.StudyMaterials;
            AppPreferenceStatus.setStudyDownload(CurContext,CourseMatIntent.StudyMaterials);
            StudyMatActivity(chapterPosition);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
   return true;
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this on your onCreateOptionsMenu?? Do it in your onCreate of your activity or some other initialize method...

Comment: I need to do this inside onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: I solved this problem move this alert on oncreate thank you @Neil